# How to create a dictionary from a pandas dataframe with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that has multiple values per identifier.

Data =

| ID | WEBPAGE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1 |
| 2 | Value2 |
| 3 | Value 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 17 | Value 3 |

I have a pandas DF of webpages and IDS. Unfortunately, sometimes two different IDs are associated with the same webpage. I dislike working with duplicates like this, but it's necessary in this case. Ideally, I'd like to get this into a format like

```
dict[WEBPAGE] = list[ID1, ID2]
```

I'd like it in this format so that each webpage only has one entry in the dictionary and can have multiple IDs associated with it if there are multiple associations.

Is this possible?

Comment: `df.groupby('WEBPAGE')['ID'].agg(list).to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Might be an overkill solution, but you could define a custom dictionary like so:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections import UserDict
from typing import Any, Hashable
import pandas as pd


def iterable_not_string(value: Any) -> bool:
    """Check if value is iterable but not a string.

    Parameters
    ----------
    value : Any
        The value to check.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True if value is iterable but not a string, False otherwise.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> iterable_not_string('abc')
    False
    >>> iterable_not_string(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    True
    >>> iterable_not_string(123)
    False
    >>> iterable_not_string(None)
    False

    Notes
    -----
    Function verifies if object is iterable by checking if it has the "__iter__" attribute.
    String objects are iterable, therefore contain the "__iter__" attribute, therefore,
    function also verifies whether `value` is an instance of `str` type.
    """
    return hasattr(value, "__iter__") and not isinstance(value, str)


def all_match(value: Any, values: Any) -> bool:
    """Check if all values in `value` are also inside `values`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    value : Any
        The value to check. Can be a single value or a list of values.
    values : Any
        The values to check against. Can be a single value or a list of values.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True if all values from `value` also exist inside `values`, False otherwise.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> all_match('a', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    True
    >>> # Function returns False, if `value` and `values` parameters get swapped, and all elements from
    >>> # `values` do not exist inside `value`.
    >>> all_match(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a')
    False
    >>> all_match(['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    True
    >>> all_match(['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    False
    """
    if not iterable_not_string(value):
        value = [value]
    if not iterable_not_string(values):
        values = [values]
    return all(v in values for v in value)


def any_match(value: Any, values: Any) -> bool:
    """Check if any values in `value` are also inside `values`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    value : Any
        The value to check. Can be a single value or a list of values.
    values : Any
        The values to check against. Can be a single value or a list of values.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True if any values from `value` also exist inside `values`, False otherwise.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> any_match('a', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    True
    >>> any_match(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a')
    """
    if not iterable_not_string(value):
        value = [value]
    if not iterable_not_string(values):
        values = [values]
    return any(v in values for v in value)


class CustomDict(UserDict):
    """
    Dictionary class for working with data that has multiple values per key.

    Parameters
    ----------
    *args : Any
        Positional arguments to pass to the `UserDict` class.
    **kwargs : Any
        Keyword arguments to pass to the `UserDict` class.
    key_column : Hashable | None, default None
        The name of the column that contains the dictionary keys.
        Parameter is used when converting the dictionary to a pandas DataFrame.
    values_column : Hashable | None, default None
        The name of the column that contains the dictionary values.

    Properties
    ----------
    original_column_names: list
        The original column names of the dictionary, as passed to the `key_column` and `values_column`
        parameters. If not provided, defaults to `[0, 1]` (key, value).
    """

    @property
    def original_column_names(self) -> list:
        key_column_name = self.key_column if self.key_column is not None else 0
        value_column_name = self.values_column if self.values_column is not None else 1
        return [key_column_name, value_column_name]

    def _repr_html_(self) -> str:
        """HTML representation of the dictionary.
        
        When running the code in an IPython, or Jupyter Notebook,
        IPython will automatically call this method to display the dictionary, instead of the default
        `__repr__` method.
        """
        key_value_pairs = "".join(
            "".join(
                "\n   <tr>"
                + f"<td>{key}</td>\n       <td>"
                + ", ".join(str(v) for v in value)
                + "</td>"
                + "\n   </tr>"
                for key, value in self.items()
            )
        )
        return f"""
        <div>
        <table border="1" class="dataframe">
        <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: right;">
            <th>key</th>
            <th>values</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{key_value_pairs}
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        """

    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        key_column: Hashable | None = None,
        values_column: Hashable | None = None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.key_column = key_column
        self.values_column = values_column
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value, if_exists: str = "replace"):
        """Set, or append a value to a dictionary key.

        Parameters
        ----------
        key : Hashable
            The key to set or append the value to.
        value : Any
            The value to set or append. Can be a single value or a list of values.
        if_exists : str {'replace', 'append'}, default 'replace'
            The method to use if the key already exists in the dictionary.
        """
        if not iterable_not_string(value):
            value = [value]
        if key not in self.keys() or (if_exists == "replace" and key in self.keys()):
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, [*self[key], *value])

    def __getitem__(self, key: Hashable) -> list:
        """Get the value of a dictionary key.

        Parameters
        ----------
        key : Hashable
            The key to get the value of.

        Returns
        -------
        list
            The value of the key. All dictionary values are stored as lists,
            even when they have a single element.
        """
        return super().__getitem__(key)

    def search(self, partial_key: str) -> "CustomDict":
        """Get the key/value pairs, that fully or partially match the dictionary keys."""
        return CustomDict(
            **{
                key: self.__getitem__(key)
                for key in self.keys()
                if partial_key in key or key in partial_key
            }
        )

    def inverse_search(self, value: Any, how: str = "any") -> "CustomDict":
        """Search for key/value pairs, based on the dictionary values.

        Parameters
        ----------
        value : Any
            The value to search for. Can be a single value or a list of values.
        how : str {'any', 'all'}, default 'any'
            The method to use for searching. If 'any', then function will return all key/value
            pairs where at least one item from `value` exists inside certain key.
            If 'all', then return only key/value pairs where all items from `value`
            exist inside certain key.

        Returns
        -------
        CustomDict
            A dictionary with key/value pairs, where the values match the search criteria.
        """
        if not iterable_not_string(value):
            value = [value]
        match_func = any_match if how == "any" else all_match
        return CustomDict(
            **{key: _value for key, _value in self.items() if match_func(value, _value)}
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_pandas(
        cls, df: pd.DataFrame, key_column: Hashable, values_column: Hashable
    ) -> "CustomDict":
        """Create a CustomDict from a pandas DataFrame."""
        d = cls(key_column=key_column, values_column=values_column)
        for key, value in zip(df[key_column], df[values_column]):
            d.__setitem__(key, value, if_exists="append")
        return d

    def to_pandas(self):
        """Convert the dictionary to a pandas DataFrame."""
        return pd.DataFrame(
            [[key, v] for key, value in self.items() for v in value],
            columns=self.original_column_names,
        )
```

### Example

```py
import pandas as pd

# == Creating Example Dataset ========================================

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'WEBPAGE': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value1', 'Value3', 'Value2', 'Value1'],
    }
)
df
# Prints:
#
#    ID WEBPAGE
# 0   1  Value1
# 1   2  Value2
# 2   3  Value1
# 3   4  Value3
# 4   5  Value2
# 5   6  Value1

# == Testing CustomDict =========================================

d = CustomDict.from_pandas(df, 'WEBPAGE', 'ID')
d
# Prints:
#
# {'Value1': [1, 3, 6], 'Value2': [2, 5], 'Value3': [4]}
```

I've also included a custom HTML representation that displays the dictionary in a similar fashion to what Pandas uses when running on interactive environments, like Jupyter:

[image]